# Material or rather a layer to increase dielectric strength

Tags: electric-fields, voltage, material-science

Is it possible to increase the dielectric strength of any or some materials by adding a certain layer on its surface?
And do you know any? The purpose is lastly to improve the electrical breakdown.

Answer (score 2):

[NASA report NASA-TM-81137 (1980)](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19800022937/downloads/19800022937.pdf) mentions potting (encapsulation) with a pottinq material that polymerizes
in place, such as polyurethane, silicone, rubber, and epoxy resins, and conformal coating, typically, with epoxy resins. There are a lot of more specific instructions in the report.

Comment: Thank you very much, will have a close look into it!

Answer (score 2):

Certainly, this is done all the time. For example, in a device called an *electrolytic capacitor*, a pair of aluminum plates are separated by a chemical paste which reacts with the aluminum to form an exceedingly thin but very robust aluminum oxide layer on the aluminum surface which serves as an excellent dielectric. As long as the oxide layer is intact, the device acts as a capacitor, in which the thinness of the film and the high dielectric constant of the oxide allow a large amount of capacitance to be squeezed into a small package.

Comment: Thank you very much as well! Do you know whether (and if how) aluminium oxide can be put as a coating onto polycarbonate?

Comment: Yes yes! There are *vacuum processes* (sputtering, chemical vapor deposition, reactive ion sputtering, etc.) that are used to put very hard dielectric coatings on plastic eyeglass lenses for scratch resistance. this is a very common practice.

Comment: Thanks a lot again, I will give this a try :)

Comment: Meanwhile, I also spoke to someone in real life who has a bit of knowledge in this field and he told me that the epsilon-difference of the connected materials is very important and it shouldn't be much different. Do you have any input for this, is this true?

Comment: I have no data. Here is some advice. It appears that you want to actually deposit some thin film on some substrate. You cannot hire someone straight out of college who knows all the practical matters related to this task, which represents an entire field of  materials process engineering whose practitioners are called *dielectric dep engineers* in the integrated circuit world. There is no way you can possibly glean enough information here to even know how to *hire* an experienced dep engineer, let alone run a dep process yourself.

Comment: Sorry if I come off as being negative about this!

Comment: no worries, I was absolutely not aware that there is even a job position for that..  but this is good so I might be able to find someone to consult. I just don't get the straight out of college point?

Comment: In practice, the technology is highly proprietary and protected by trade secret status, nondisclosure requirements, and noncompete clauses. So while you might learn the basics in college, you cannot stride purposefully out the gates and go into business running a dep operation by yourself armed with just a fresh college degree. That is what I meant.